# Rails 4.2 - Creating an action for a belongs_to model (Thinkster.io Angular + Rails Tutorial)

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the AngularJS + Rails tutorial from here https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ and have ran into a wall at the "Finishing Off Comments" section towards the end (right after it says "To enable adding comments, we can use the same technique we used for adding new posts"). Specifically, the server is throwing a 500 when I hit the /posts/{id}/comments.json endpoint.

The error I get is `` undefined local variable or method `post' for #<CommentsController:0x5f72b38> ``.

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments

    def as_json(options = {})
        # Make all JSON representations of posts include the comments
        super(options.merge(include: :comments))
    end
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

postsCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',
    'post',
    function($scope, posts, post) {
        $scope.post = post;

        $scope.addComment = function(){
          if($scope.body === '') { return; }
          posts.addComment(post.id, {
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user'
          }).success(function(comment) {
            $scope.post.comments.push(comment)
          });

          $scope.body = '';
        };
    }]);
```

posts.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', [
    '$http',
    function($http) {
        // Service Body
        var o = {
            posts: []
        };

        o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data) {
                angular.copy(data, o.posts)
            });
        };

        o.create = function(post) {
            return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data) {
                o.posts.push(data);
            });
        };

        o.upvote = function(post) {
            return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json')
                .success(function(data) {
                    post.upvotes += 1;
                });
        }

        o.get = function(id) {
            return $http.get('/posts/' + id + '.json').then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
        };

        o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
            return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments.json', comment);
        }

        return o;
}]);
```

And finally comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        comment = post.comments.create(comment_params)
        respond_with post, comment
    end

    def upvote
        comment = post.comments.find(params[:id])
        comment.increment!(:upvotes)

        respond_with post, comment
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

I understand that it's complaining about the reference to post in the create action, but I don't know why Rails isn't just recognizing it as the post the comment belongs to. I'm very new to Rails but I can't see anything I've done differently from the tutorial. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: hey man, sorry for bothering you with off-topic - did you manage to complete the tutorial? Cause I've stuck on Wiring Everything Up#Loading posts.. Could you please, if that's not a problem, provide me with a link to your github, where I can take a look at something? Would be really appreciated. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoo boy I feel stupid now. I added the following line to the top of the create action and it works now: `post = Post.find(params[:post_id])` Hope this helps anyone else who gets stuck anyway! The tutorial seems to be missing this part.